# Callback Problem: Can't return a value from a method with void result type

Tags: java, android

I want to return the `List<Product>` as result value without blocking, how is it done?

```
public static List<Product> getProducts(@NonNull Context context){

    ProductDataSource.getInstance(context).readProducts(new IProductDataSource.IReadProductsCallback() {
        @Override
        public void onSuccess(List<Product> result) {
            return result; // error in here
        }

        @Override
        public void onFailure() {
            return null;  // error in here
        }
    });

}
```

Comment: have you never learned what 'void' means? it means it doesn't return anything. You're not supposed to return anything there.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57330766/how-to-get-data-from-any-asynchronous-operation-in-android have a look at this

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to provide some sort of a callback to the calling method. For example:

```
interface Callback {
  void onProductsRetrieved(List<Product> products)
  void onProductsRetrieveError()
}

public static void getProducts(@NonNull Context context, Callback callback) {
  ProductDataSource
    .getInstance(context)
    .readProducts(new IProductDataSource.IReadProductsCallback() {
      @Override
      public void onSuccess(List<Product> result) {
        callback.onProductsRetrieved(result)
      }

      @Override
      public void onFailure() {
        callback.onProductsRetrieveError()
      }
    });
}
```

Note the return type for `getProducts` has been changed to `void` and a `Callback` has been added as a parameter.

Alternatively you can pass in your `IProductDataSource.IReadProductsCallback` directly:

```
public static void getProducts(@NonNull Context context, IProductDataSource.IReadProductsCallback callback) {
  ProductDataSource.getInstance(context).readProducts(callback);
}
```